# get value in pyspark dataframe

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark, pyspark

I have problems getting the values for one particular column, when reading the dataframe through MongoDB Connector for Spark.

Row in DataFrame:

```py
Row(
    __v=0,
    _id=Row(oid="1"),
    back=Row(
        attrs=Row(version=1),
        content=[
            Row(
                content=[
                    Row(
                        content=None,
                        text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr",
                        type="text",
                    )
                ],
                type="paragraph",
            )
        ],
        type="doc",
    ),
    createdAt=datetime.datetime(2021, 7, 29, 17, 33, 17, 633000),
    updatedAt=datetime.datetime(2021, 7, 29, 17, 42, 10, 31000),
)
```

What I'd like is to get the vlaue inside `text=''` as a column

Scheme:

```
   root
 |-- __v: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- _id: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- oid: string (nullable = true)
 |-- back: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- attrs: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- version: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |-- content: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- content: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- content: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- type: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- content: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- type: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- text: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- text: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- type: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- type: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- type: string (nullable = true)
 |-- createdAt: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- updatedAt: timestamp (nullable = true)
```

Comment: are you working with row objects or a dataframe ?

Comment: I'm working with a dataframe. I added the scheme to my original post.

Comment: I added a solution using explodes. according to your schema, you have 4 arrays, so need 4 explodes. But if you understand the logic, you can adjust the number if your case change. I put each `withColumn` in a different assignation, but of course, you can chain them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`content` are arrays that contains arrays ... nested arrays. You have to use `explode` 4 times I believe to explode each array.
Assuming df is your dataframe, I would do something like this :

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = df.withColumn(
    "content",
    F.explode("back.content")
)

df = df.withColumn(
    "content",
    F.explode("content.content")
)

df = df.withColumn(
    "content",
    F.explode("content.content")
)

df = df.withColumn(
    "content",
    F.explode("content.content")
)

df = df.withColumn(
    "text",
    F.col("content.text"),
)
```

Comment: I get following error when executing the last df.withColumn(..): AssertionError: col should be Column